# ASP.NET Core: NullReferenceException on getting foreign key

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, nullreferenceexception, asp.net-core-identity

I am working on a booking system for computer club.

I am getting `NullReferenceException` when I try to get a foreign key of an instance.

**Example:**

```
var queue = _db.Queues.First(q => q.Index == 1);
Console.WriteLine(queue.QueueId); // works fine (primary key)
Console.WriteLine(queue.Index); // works fine (simple property)
Console.WriteLine(queue.User.Id); // NullReferenceException (foreign key)
```

The `queue` itself, obviously, is not null but `queue.User` is null. How's that possible?

Comment: it's not clear from your example how the variable `queue1` is related to `queue`. what justifies your assertion that the non-nullness of one implies the non-nullness of the other? also, why tag this with asp core identity? can you explain why it's relevant?

Comment: @djeikyb ignore `queue1` I simply forgot to remove it. It was added for testing purposes

Comment: @djeikyb I did tag asp net core identity because I get an exception only when I call `queue.User.Id` – other properties of `Queue` work fine

Comment: do `queue.User?.Id` it won't throw an exception if `User` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Include` in your EF core query.Refer to [Loading related data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1).

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var queue =_db.Queues.Include(q => q.User).First(q => q.Index == 1);
```